# sql query to search from 2 fields mysql Fulltext

Tags: mysql

I have a search that searches for songs in a database, currently they can search by artist or the title of the song. So at the moment they could search tom jones or its not unusual they couldn't search tom jones unusual. How do I make this possible my current SQL looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM songs  
WHERE artist LIKE '%$search%' 
   OR songname LIKE '%$search%' 
LIMIT 6
```

I have added full text search to the artist and songname columns. Can't work out how to search on both rows.

Comment: Have you tried changing the OR in the WHERE clause to an AND?

Comment: using AND would make it need to be in both fields, I need it so it can be in either or both, not only in both. If it was and and the user searched to only items with to in both fields would show ie Elton John - Step onto Christmas. as both fields contain to

Comment: You probably want full text search.

Comment: Cheers Gornon Linoff Full text seems to be the way to make this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is using full text search. You first need to define the rows you want to use in full text search you can do this with the following mysql command

```
ALTER TABLE  songs 
ADD FULLTEXT(artist, songtitle)
```

and then the sql query is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE MATCH (songname, artist) AGAINST ('$search')  LIMIT 6";
```

This will return results only when there is a matching word if you want like results before a full word is typed you can so something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE MATCH (songname, artist) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  LIMIT 6";
$sqllike = "SELECT * FROM songs  WHERE artist like '%$search%' OR songname like '%$search%' LIMIT 6";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultlike = mysqli_query($con, $sqllike);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='". $row["songid"] . "' class='songclicker'>";
        echo "<div class='song whitefont'>";
        echo "<img src='" . $row["artwork"]."' class='songimage'>";
        echo "<p>". $row["songname"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>". $row["artist"] . "</p></div>";

    }
    echo "<a href='". urlencode($search) ."'><h1 class='seeall'>See all search results</h1></a>";
} else {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultlike) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultlike)) {
        echo "<a href='". $row["songid"] . "' class='songclicker'>";
        echo "<div class='song whitefont'>";
        echo "<img src='" . $row["artwork"]."' class='songimage'>";
        echo "<p>". $row["songname"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>". $row["artist"] . "</p></div>";

    }

    echo "<a href='searchresults.php'><h1 class='seeall'>See all search results</h1></a>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `tom jones unusual` as your search text `'$search'`. When you are using `like` in `mysql` it will search for the text pattern in the given field but when you enter `tom jones unusual` as the search text there are no occurrences for such a text. Because `tom jones` is in one field and `unusual` is in the other field

You can do following to get done what you want

- get the full search text `tom jones unusual`
- split the search text from the white spaces in to separate variables ex `$ser1 = tom; $ser2 = jones; $ser3 = unusual;`
- then do something like this in `mysql`

`select * from song where artist like '%$ser1%' or '%$ser2%' or '%$ser3%' or songname like '%$ser1%' or '%$ser2%' or '%$ser3%'`

Comment: This would work however it would fail to narrow down the search results, Lets say I search Beach boys, It will give me all the Beach boys songs. If I then added I get around so my search is now beach boys I get around I would still get all the songs containing beach boys but not I get around. From reading the docs I think full text search is the solution I just cant work out how to use it